# Using linear approximation to approximate $\sqrt{81.3}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, linear-approximation

> Use linear approximaiton to approximate $\sqrt{81.3}$ as follows: Let $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$. The equation of the tangent line to $f(x)$ at $x=81$ can be written in the form $y=mx+b$ where $m$ is:____ and where $b$ is:_____

I calculated:

$f'(x)=1/2x^{-1/2}= 1/18=m$

$f(x)=\sqrt{81}=9=b$, why is this wrong for $b$? Am I missing something?

Comment: Why do you feel this is wrong?

Comment: You want $mx_0 + b = f(x_0)$. So $b = f(x_0)$ only if $x_0 = 0$ (or $m = 0$). You can start by writing it as $m(x-x_0) + f(x_0)$.

Comment: @DannyW. The online homework says it's incorrect.

Comment: I think there is a subtlety here - look at this:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_approximation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall point-slope form at a point $(x_0,y_0)$:
$$y = m(x-x_0) + y_0.$$
Now, recasting in this in Calculus terms, we have the line tangent to $f$, here $\ell(x)$, at the point $(x_0,f(x_0))$:
$$\ell(x) = f'(x_0)(x-x_0) + f(x_0).$$
You correctly found $f'(x_0)$ and $f(x_0)$; but notice that this information defines the line in point-slope form, i.e.,
$$\ell(x) = \frac{1}{18}(x - 81) + 9.$$
Do you see how this is not yet in slope-intercept form? ($y=mx + b$). Some simplification is in order.

Answer (score 2):

Point :  $(81, 9)$
Slope : $\dfrac{1}{18}$

[Point-slope](http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/line-equation-point-slope.html) form of line would be : $$y-9 =  \dfrac{1}{18}(x-81)$$

Change it into slope-intercept form

Comment: So wouldn't $b$ be $9$?

Comment: No. send that 9 to other side, simplify a bit and change it into the required form :  $$y = mx + b$$

Comment: I see, thanks +1

Comment: you're welcome!